# C# Get Data from array in same way like i can in php

Tags: c#, arrays

how can get data from array in same way like i can in php?

```
$arr = array(
    '123' => 'abc',
    '456' => 'def'
);
echo $arr['123']; // abc
```

How can i do same with array's at C#?

Comment: What would you like to have as result?

Comment: I just want to access specific data at array by it's name without searching in array each time when i need it.

Comment: I think what your looking for is a Dictionary<int, string>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {123, "abc"}, {456, "def"}
};
Console.WriteLine(dict[123]);  // abc
```